# How to select a corresponding column in mysql for a MAX DATE grouped by DATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**mysql table: stats**

```
columns: 
         date           | stats
05-05-2015 22:25:00     | 78
05-05-2015 09:25:00     | 21
05-05-2015 05:25:00     | 25
05-04-2015 09:25:00     | 29
05-04-2015 05:25:00     | 15
```

**sql query:**

```
SELECT MAX(date) as date, stats FROM stats GROUP BY date(date) ORDER BY date DESC
```

when I do this, I does select one row per date (grouped by date, regardless of the time), and selects the largest date with `MAX`, but it does not select the corresponding column. 
for example, it returns `05-05-2015 22:25:00` as the `date`, and `25` as the `stats`. It should be selecting `78` as the `stats`. I've done my research and seems like solutions to this are out there, but I am not familiar with `JOIN` or other less-common mysql functions to achieve this, and it's hard for me to understand other examples/solutions so I decided to post my own specific scenario.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

This question is asked every single day in SO. Sometimes, it's correctly answered too. Anyway, purists won't like it but here's one option:

```
Select x.* from stats x join (SELECT MAX(date) max_date FROM stats GROUP BY date(date)) y on y.max_date = x.date;
```

Obviously, for this to work dates need to be stored using a datetime data type.